# What is the query to access a data with the foreign key within Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to list the data of the table sale, accessing the name of the user with the foreign key userId, what is the correct way to do this with the context?

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var comic = context.sale.Select(d => d);
}

public class sale
{
    public int saleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<sale>()
            .HasOne<user>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.userId);
```

Comment: To do it "smoothly" without explicit join you need to create navigation property of type `user` in `sale` class. Then you will be able to do `context.sales.Include(s => s.User).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter you classes to add navigation properties:

```
public class sale
{
    public int saleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public user user { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public ICollection<sale> sales { get; set; } = new HashSet<sale>();
};
```

Then change your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<sale>()
            .HasOne(a => a.user)
            .WithMany(a => a.sales)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.userId);
```

You can then get the related data with:

```
var user = context.sale.Include(a => a.user)...
```

Comment: doing this adds the sale table, it is left with a column userId and userId1, is this ok ?, what data should I save in userId1?

Comment: It shouldn't add an extra column, which version of EF are you using?